# flutter problem : How to create a button like this?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create like this button
[image]

But I am creating like this
[image]

[image]

when I m removing this line then I got error

```
  right: BorderSide(
   color: skyBlue,
   width: 2.0,),
```

This is my code

```
Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        tabValue = 'Growth';
                                      });
                                      print(tabValue);
                                    },
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          bottom: 10, top: 10),
                                      child: Container(
                                        width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2.24,

                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            border: Border(
                                              left: BorderSide(
                                                  color: skyBlue,
                                                  width: 2.0,
                                                  style: BorderStyle.solid),
                                              top: BorderSide(
                                                  color: skyBlue,
                                                  width: 2.0,
                                                  style: BorderStyle.solid),
                                              bottom: BorderSide(
                                                  color: skyBlue,
                                                  width: 2.0,
                                                  style: BorderStyle.solid),
                                              right: BorderSide(
                                                  color: skyBlue,
                                                  width: 2.0,),
                                            ),
                                            boxShadow: tabValue == 'Growth' ? <BoxShadow>[
                                                  BoxShadow(
                                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                                      blurRadius: 2,
                                                      offset: Offset(0.50, 1)
                                                  )
                                                ]:<BoxShadow>[
                                                  BoxShadow(
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      blurRadius: 0,
                                                      offset: Offset(0,0)
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              color: tabValue == 'Growth'
                                                  ? skyBlue
                                                  : Colors.white,
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                              topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                                            ),),
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Growth",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 14,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                                color: tabValue == 'Growth'
                                                    ? Colors.white
                                                    : skyBlue),
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          )),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                              
                                  InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        tabValue = 'Home Loan';
                                      });
                                      print(tabValue);
                                    },
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          bottom: 10, top: 10),
                                      child: Container(
                                          width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2.4,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              border: Border.all(
                                                  color: green2Color,
                                                  width: 2.0,
                                                  style: BorderStyle.solid),
                                              boxShadow: tabValue == 'Home Loan' ? <BoxShadow>[
                                                BoxShadow(
                                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                                    blurRadius: 2,
                                                    offset: Offset(0.50, 1)
                                                )
                                              ]:<BoxShadow>[
                                                BoxShadow(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    blurRadius: 0,
                                                    offset: Offset(0,0)
                                                )
                                              ],
                                              color: tabValue == 'Home Loan'
                                                  ? green2Color
                                                  : Colors.white,
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                              topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
                                            ),),
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              horizontal: 10, vertical: 15),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Home Loan",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 14,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                                color: tabValue == 'Home Loan'
                                                    ? Colors.white
                                                    : green2Color),
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          )),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
```

Comment: You want to remove the center green line?

Comment: What's error you got?

Comment: @SuganPandurengan yes i want to remove center green line

Comment: @SuganPandurengan I am getting this error "A borderRadius can only be given for a uniform Border."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow set borderRadius only when you define all border side same or not define each one of them, try this:

```
Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    tabValue = 'Growth';
                  });
                  print(tabValue);
                },
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 10),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, left: 2, bottom: 2),
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.24,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                        ),
                        boxShadow: tabValue == 'Growth'
                            ? <BoxShadow>[
                                BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    blurRadius: 2,
                                    offset: Offset(0.50, 1))
                              ]
                            : <BoxShadow>[
                                BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    blurRadius: 0,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 0))
                              ],
                        color:
                            tabValue == 'Growth' ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
                      ),
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
                      child: Text(
                        "Growth",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            color: tabValue == 'Growth'
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.blue),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      )),
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    tabValue = 'Home Loan';
                  });
                  print(tabValue);
                },
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 10),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, right: 2, bottom: 2),
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.4,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
                        ),
                        boxShadow: tabValue == 'Home Loan'
                            ? <BoxShadow>[
                                BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    blurRadius: 2,
                                    offset: Offset(0.50, 1))
                              ]
                            : <BoxShadow>[
                                BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    blurRadius: 0,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 0))
                              ],
                        color: tabValue == 'Home Loan'
                            ? Colors.green
                            : Colors.white,
                      ),
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 15),
                      child: Text(
                        "Home Loan",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            color: tabValue == 'Home Loan'
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.green),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      )),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
```

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @Deepak

Comment: Thsnk you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the right border color as transparent.

```dart
 right: BorderSide(
   color: Colors.transparent,
   width: 2.0,),
```